# How to format expl3 floating point number using siunitx

Tags: siunitx, expl3

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\fp_new:N  \mynumber
\fp_set:Nn \mynumber{5}
\fp_div:Nn \mynumber{2}

\mynumber
\\
\num{\mynumber}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Prints:

```
+2.500000000e0
2.500 000 000
```

How can I make it print:

```
+2.500000000e0
2.5
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

- `\fp_eval:n` or `\fp_to_decimal:N` (which are “identical”), or
- `\fp_to_scientific:N`

to create a TeX output that can serve as a `siunitx` input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\fp_new:N  \mynumber
\fp_set:Nn \mynumber{5}
\fp_div:Nn \mynumber{2}

\fp_eval:n          \mynumber \par
\fp_to_decimal:N    \mynumber \par
\fp_to_scientific:N \mynumber \par

\num{\fp_to_decimal:N\mynumber}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\fp_use:N` and `\fp_to_decimal:N` are copies of each other and expect a single floating point variable.  `\fp_eval:n` and `\fp_to_decimal:n` are copies of each other and accept any expression within braces.